# Pre-requisites for installing SharePoint 2010 Project Templates in Visual Studio 2012

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, visual-studio-2012, project-templates

I want to start work on SP 2010 with Visual Studio 2012 ,  but I am unable to see any SharePoint Project Templates for creating a Visual Web Part.

What should be installed for getting the SharePoint Project Templates? And can anyone provide a link what are the pre-requisites for the same?

My environment is Windows 7 Enterprise, SP 2010 installed [ No Separate SQL Server installed ].

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to install the office developer tools for Visual Studio to get all the templates your looking for.

Here is a [link](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vsto/archive/2013/03/06/office-developer-tools-for-visual-studio-2012-now-available.aspx) to a msdn blog.